# Create an instance of an internal class within the same assembly from the name of the class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, types

I am trying to create instances of internal classes that are in the same assembly as the calling class. Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I'm using the following code snippet:

```
Assembly businessAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
var concreteValidator = businessAssembly.CreateInstance(t.NotificationType.ValidatorClassName, true,
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
    null, 
    new Object[] { t }, 
    null, 
    null);
```

Note that `t.NotificationType.ValidatorClassName` is in the form `Namespace.ClassName`.
Shouldn't that do the job? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the CreateInstance(String) overload?

Comment: What is "did not work".  Do you get an exception of any kind?

Comment: What is the value for `ValidatorClassName`?

Comment: Is the constructor on your internal class also `internal`?  It should work if that's the case.

Comment: "Did not work" means that the value of `concreteValidator` was null. It did not throw an exception. And the constructor is actually `public`, not `internal`. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class is <s>public</s> internal and the constructor is public, then the `CreateInstance` method is missing the public binding flag:

```
BindingFlags.Public
```

Which would become:

```
Assembly businessAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
var concreteValidator = businessAssembly.CreateInstance(t.NotificationType.ValidatorClassName, true,
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public, 
    null, 
    new Object[] { t }, 
    null, 
    null);
```

Comment: OP said it was internal, not public.

Comment: My mistake; still, if the class is internal, then the public binding flag needs to be included.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  If the class and the c'tor are `internal`, `BindingFlags.Public` will cause a `MissingMethodException`.

Comment: If the class is internal and the constructor is public, `BindingFlags.Public` is still needed.

Comment: I've just tested it. When I made the constructor `internal` it worked fine. When I made the constructor `public` and added `BindingFlags.Public` it worked fine as well. Thanks for you help :)